# BindingExpression not Valid for ListCollectionView in CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, collections

I need to have a collection displayed in a ListView. For that, i have a CompositeCollection with one ListViewItem as a searchbar for the collection. I put it together with a list of "n" items. The reason to do that, is that i need the searchbar is not influenced by sorting. The problem is, that the CollectionView i bind to a CollectionViewSource produces an BindingError and i don´t know why.

My XAML-Code for the Collections:

```
<Grid.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ElementSource" Source="{Binding ElementsCollectionView}"/>
      <CompositeCollection x:Key="CompositeCollection">
           <ListViewItem Content="{Binding HeaderRow}"/>
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ElementSource}}"/>
      </CompositeCollection>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And the Collections I use

```
private NotifyCollection<DataEntry> _data;
public NotifyCollection<DataEntry> Data
{
    get { return this._data; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._data, value); }
}

private CollectionView _elementsCollectionView;
public CollectionView ElementsCollectionView
{
    get { return this._elementsCollectionView; }
    set
    {
        if (value == null) return;
        this._elementsCollectionView = value;
    }
}

private CompositeCollection _tableItems;
public CompositeCollection TableItems
{
    get { return this._tableItems; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._tableItems, value); }
}

private DataEntry _headerRow;
public DataEntry HeaderRow
{
    get { return this._headerRow; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this._headerRow, value); }
}
```

And the Collections being initalised:

```
public void SetCollection()
{
    this.TableItems.Add(this.HeaderRow);
    this.TableItems.Add(this.ElementsCollectionView);
}

this.TableViewModel.ElementsCollectionView =  
     (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Data);
```

As you can see, everything seem´s ok. The NotifyCollection inherits from ObservableCollection and should do hte work. If I add the HeaderRow to to the "ElementsCollectionView" everything works fine, except the HeaderRow is sorted. If i add the CollectionView to the CollectionViewSource, i get the BindingError:

```
 System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is      
 not valid for target property.; 
 Value='System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' 
 BindingExpression:Path=ElementsCollectionView; 
 DataItem='AuftragsverwaltungDataTableViewModel' (HashCode=57170378); 
 target element is 'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=52642430); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the `Source` property of a `CollectionViewSource` to a `ListCollectionView`. This will throw an `ArgumentException`. Sort the `NotifyCollection<DataEntry>` collection and bind to this one instead.